# how to set a div to the bottom side in asp.net css

Tags: css, asp.net

I am trying to make a div stay always on the bottom page.even when the user scroll down, it to appear in the end. 
this is the css code

```
#CenterPanel {
    position: absolute;

    bottom: 0px;
    left:0;

    width: 100%;
    height: 85%;

    background-color: green;
}

.CenterPanels {
    position: relative;

    border: 2px solid #303641;
    width: 28%;
    height: 30%;

    margin: 10px;
    float: left;

    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

and asp.net code for 10 div's and the center panel:

```
 <div id="CenterPanel">

    <div class="CenterPanels">
        1
    </div>
    <div  class="CenterPanels">
        2
    </div>
    <div  class="CenterPanels">
        3
    </div>
    <div  class="CenterPanels">
        4
    </div>
    <div  class="CenterPanels">
        5
    </div>
    <div  class="CenterPanels">
        6
    </div>
    <div  class="CenterPanels">
        7
    </div>
    <div  class="CenterPanels">
        8
    </div>
    <div  class="CenterPanels">
        9
    </div>
    <div  class="CenterPanels">
        10
    </div>
</div>
```

it should appear like this:
[image: img1]

but if you scroll down. I keep getting this:
[image: img2]

the green part should be in the bottom. but it doesnt.

I want to use just css to do this, not javascript or anything else.
I tried to use

```
  bottom: 0px;
  bottom: 0%;
```

but nothing is working. any suggestion?

Comment: why do people keep deleting their answers?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. Which div should be always at bottom? Isn't it correct to show the 10th div if you scroll down?

Comment: @krlzlx CenterPanel should be always on bottom. a footer. but when you scroll down, the footer goes up..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `overflow:auto`  to your container div.

```css
#CenterPanel {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 85%;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
}
.CenterPanels {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #303641;
  width: 28%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="CenterPanel">

  <div class="CenterPanels">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="CenterPanels">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="CenterPanels">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="CenterPanels">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="CenterPanels">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="CenterPanels">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="CenterPanels">
    7
  </div>
  <div class="CenterPanels">
    8
  </div>
  <div class="CenterPanels">
    9
  </div>
  <div class="CenterPanels">
    10
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this in your footer? If so, trying setting "position: fixed;" in the CSS for the footer

Comment: with it fixed, I can not scroll down and see the 10th div